# Nginx: redirect location based on multiple args

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an nginx location redirect set up to redirect `/my_route` to a coming soon page, but allow `/my_route?db=preview` to pass through to the proxy server.

```
location /my_route {
  if ($arg_db != "preview") {
    rewrite ^ /coming-soon/ last;
  }
  <other location config for when db == preview>
}
```

I want to add an additional layer of complexity, to support multiple languages for the coming soon page.

Config that breaks nginx, but give you the idea:

```
location /my_route {
  if ($arg_db != "preview") {
    if ($arg_lang == "es") {
      rewrite ^ /coming-soon/index_es.html last;
    }
    rewrite ^ /coming-soon/ last;
  }
  <other location config for when db == preview>
}
```

I know that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), so I'm happy to move away from using `if`, if that's what is needed, but I don't know which direction to look. I just know nginx doesn't support `&&` statements, or nested `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `map` to eliminate the inner `if` block.

For example:

```
map $arg_lang $mylang {
    default   /;
    es        /index_es.html;
}
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^ /coming_soon$mylang last;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.